# How do I do a DB dump from server to local machine directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have an Ubuntu server running on digital ocean for a client, and they want me to create a db dump of a rails app, using postgresql.

I'd like to know what command that I can run to do a postgresql db dump to my local machine directly from the server. I DO NOT want to dump it on the server than download it, but rather, directly dump it to my machine.

I've tried

```
ssh user@remote_machine "pg_dump -U dbuser -h localhost -C --column-inserts" \

 >> backup_file_on_your_local_machine.sql
```

How can I do this? I know it's possible

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to have the postgres client installed on your local machine and then run specifying the host where the db instance is running. Assuming it is running on the default postgres port 5432, you can pull the dump by running:

`pg_dump -h DBHOST -U USERNAME -d DBNAME > file_name.pgsql`

**update**: you can usually find the port in the config/database.yml or in the environment variable. It will most likely be 5432.

Comment: Thanks! How can I find out what port it's running on?

Comment: What is DBHOST? Is that the digital ocean server? Also there is no -d pg_dump: invalid option -- d

Comment: DBHOST is the remote machine address. In your case it's what you put in "remote_machine". Could be a domain, url or ip address.

Comment: But yes, it's your digital ocean server where postgres is running. The port should be 5432 most likely